# Block short URL in robots.txt

Tags: search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, noindex

We have `example.com/article-page-one/` 
This page has a short URL in Wordpress like this : `example.com/?p=1` 
In this page we put short URL for users.
What will happen if we block short URL? 
The robots.txt file will be like this:
`disallow: /*?p=*` 
Will `example.com/article-page-one/` de-indexed form Google?

Answer (score -1):

The pretty URL version will not be affected by Google if you remove the one with the `?` in it.

That said I posit you would be better off doing a 301 (permanent) redirect to the pretty URL and I suspect that ove4 time Google will de-index the variant with the `?`.

Comment: Do you mean "disallow the one with the `?` in it"?